# How to select and repeat a number of rows in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, rep

I believe my question is quite simple, but I can't manage to find the right answer.

In any given dataframe:

```
> data.frame(x0=c(1,2,3,4), x1=rnorm(4))
  x0         x1
1  1 -0.1868765
2  2 -0.2935534
3  3 -1.3934953
4  4  0.8165035
```

Imagine I'd like to take every two rows and repeat it by 2 times ending up with something like this:

```
> data.frame(x0=c(1,2,3,4), x1=rnorm(4))
  x0         x1
1  1 -0.1868765
2  2 -0.2935534
3  1 -0.1868765
4  2 -0.2935534
5  3 -1.3934953
6  4  0.8165035
7  3 -1.3934953
8  4  0.8165035
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would be another option: `c(do.call(rbind, replicate(2, matrix(seq_len(nrow(your_data)), 2), simplify = FALSE)))`

Comment: Tried it and it works well too, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create group of 2 rows and repeat it twice for each group,  unlist the indices and subset.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x0=c(1,2,3,4), x1=rnorm(4))

inds <- seq(nrow(df))
df[unlist(tapply(inds, ceiling(inds/2), rep, 2)), ]

#    x0          x1
#1    1 -0.56047565
#2    2 -0.23017749
#1.1  1 -0.56047565
#2.1  2 -0.23017749
#3    3  1.55870831
#4    4  0.07050839
#3.1  3  1.55870831
#4.1  4  0.07050839
```

Comment: There it is, this actually makes the trick! Thanks very much :)

Comment: Though I actually thought it would be simpler, i have to admit.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could just do that using `rep`.

```
d[rep(seq(nrow(d)), each=2), ]
# x0          x1
# 1    1 -0.56047565
# 1.1  1 -0.56047565
# 2    2 -0.23017749
# 2.1  2 -0.23017749
# 3    3  1.55870831
# 3.1  3  1.55870831
# 4    4  0.07050839
# 4.1  4  0.07050839
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(x0 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), x1 = c(-0.560475646552213, 
-0.23017748948328, 1.55870831414912, 0.070508391424576)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: I like this one. Though its not exactly what OP wants. He wants 1 and 2 repeated, then 3 and 4 etc. and not 1 repeated, 2 repeated etc. Not sure, if that would make a dfifference for him.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   uncount(2) %>%
   as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#     x0      x1
#  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1 -0.560 
#2     1 -0.560 
#3     2 -0.230 
#4     2 -0.230 
#5     3  1.56  
#6     3  1.56  
#7     4  0.0705
#8     4  0.0705
```

#### data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x0=c(1,2,3,4), x1=rnorm(4))
```

Comment: Thanks akron! Out of curiosity, I see 2 is the parameter which estimates the row count, what about the repeat? what if i want to repeat these two rows, for instance, 5 times? This is, in fact, the question, in your proposal the result is not exactly what is wanted.

Comment: @UnaiVicente if you want to repeat 5 times, change the 2 to 5.  Is that your question?

Comment: Nope, if you look carefully at my example, you'll see two different specifications are needed, your proposal only takes 1 into account. Therefore, it does not do what I was asking. Thanks though!